# Datepicker show legenda below months disappears on click next month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a nice legenda below my datepicker and it works fine, until you click on next month. I added the link because it is difficult to explain, click on the tab "Prijzen 2013" and than click on periode toevoegen to add a datepicker.

https://www.huurhulp.nl/wijzigen/wijzigen.php?wijzigen_adv=4&code=321fa6715e552e9bd495753f44b04db8

This is the function that does the job (beforeshow in the datepicker):

```javascript
function insertMessage() {
    var legenda = '<div class="legenda"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:11px;color:silver;"><tr><td>Let op! Overlap in afwijkende prijzen is niet mogelijk.</td><td>Gesloten:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="background-color:red;width:15px;"></td>'
    legenda = legenda + '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Afwijkende prijs:</td><td style="background-color:#00A800;width:15px;"></td></tr></table></div>';
    clearTimeout(insertMessage.timer);
    if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar').is(':visible')){
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').append(legenda);
    }
    else {
       insertMessage.timer = setTimeout(insertMessage, 10);
    }
}
```

i tried this, but doesn't work:

```javascript
$('#ui-datepicker-div').delegate('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next', 'click', insertMessage);
```

Comment: Why don't you simply insert the legend in a separate div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear), the `onChangeMonthYear` function is probably what you need.

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker({
  ...
  onChangeMonthYear: function( year, month, inst ) {
    insertMessage();
    },
  }
});
```

Or something similar. It is called when the datepicker moves to a new month/year.

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar thx, just update the code, got the wrong hook.

Comment: Thanks, did the job (for a part). I also changed the function a bit:

Answer (score 2):

```
function insertMessage(next) {
var legenda = '<div class="legenda"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:11px;color:silver;"><tr><td>Let op! Overlap in afwijkende prijzen is niet mogelijk.</td><td>Gesloten:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="background-color:red;width:15px;"></td>';
legenda = legenda + '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Afwijkende prijs:</td><td style="background-color:#00A800;width:15px;"></td></tr></table></div>';
clearTimeout(insertMessage.timer);
if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar').is(':visible')){
    if (next == 1){
        insertMessage.timer = setTimeout(insertMessage, 10);
    }        
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').append(legenda);
}
else {
   insertMessage.timer = setTimeout(insertMessage, 10);
}
```

}